# How can I fix 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token <' when testing a React build with Firebase Hosting emulator?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' when testing Firebase Hosting emulator with React build

I have a React application and I'm trying to test it locally using the Firebase Hosting emulator. I have successfully built the application using yarn build, and the build folder contains the necessary files. However, when I access the local URL provided by the Firebase Hosting emulator, I receive the error message "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" in the browser console.

I have checked the Firebase Hosting configuration, ensured that the "public" property in firebase.json is set to "build", and restarted the Firebase Hosting emulator. Additionally, I have cleared the browser cache and retried the local URL, but the issue persists.

firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any javascript or HTML files you can share on this? Does it work with an empty JS file? How can one reproduce the error?